# Degree three, codimension one subvarieties lying on a quadratic hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, projective-varieties, enumerative-geometry

Let $H$ be an irreducible hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ of large-ish degree, say 14. This question is about subvarieties $V$ of $H$ such that

- $V$ has codimension 1 in $H$ (i.e. $V$ has dimension $n-2$),
- $V$ has degree 3, and
- $V$ is contained in a quadratic hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$.

Can $H$ have infinitely many such subvarieties? If $H$ has infinitely many such subvarieties, what does that say about $H$?

Comment: Are these subvarieties all iterated cones on cubic normal curves?

Comment: @WillSawin: it could also be an iterated cone over a cubic scroll.

Comment: @Sasha . . . or it could be a linearly degenerate variety that is a cubic hypersurface in a hyperplane (and the quadratic hypersurface is a reducible quadratic hypersurface).

Comment: @JasonStarr: right, and this covers all possibilities.

Comment: @Sasha would you consider posting that as an answer (with an epsilon more detail)? This trichotomy would already be enough for the application I have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the linear span of $V$ has dimension $n-1$, then $V$ is a cubic hypersurface in a hyperplane. Otherwise, $V$ is a **variety of minimal degree**, hence it is a cone over a linear section of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$, see Corollary 1.12 in [Saint-Donat, B. Projective models of $K-3$ surfaces. Amer. J. Math. 96 (1974), 602--639].

Comment: If I remember MO protocol correctly I should wait a day or so before accepting this as the answer. But it gives all the information I need, I think - in particular about the codimension of the singular locus of the quadratic hypersurface, which is very restricted in my application.

Comment: Having looked at that reference the other results given there are very explicit and helpful, so much so I will accept the answer now.